# Django:How to return nowhere?

Tags: python, django, redirect, return

***(sorry for my bad english)***

**hello mans.i have a such view in django:**

```
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        favelan = get_object_or_404(elan,id = id)
        isfav = True
        if favelan.favorit.filter(id = request.user.id).exists():
            favelan.favorit.remove(request.user)
            messages.success(request,'Elan Uluzlulardan Silindi!')
            isfav = False
            return redirect("/",{'isfav':isfav})
        else:
            favelan.favorit.add(request.user)
            messages.success(request,'Elan Uluzlulara Elave Olundu!')
            isfav = True
            return redirect("/",{'isfav':isfav})
    return redirect('/hesablar/qeydiyyat')
```

**i want this view redirect user nowhere.how i do this?i tried:**

```
reqabspath = request.path  
return redirect(reqabspath,{'isfav':isfav})
```

**but its not working.i want redirect user nowhere.please help me.thanks now.**

Comment: Can you specify what you mean redirect user nowhere

Comment: I have a add to favorites button on a few of my pages. When this button is clicked, it directs me to the root directory. I want it not to direct me anywhere. I hope I tell you.

Comment: Return an empty response with code 204.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to the page on which user was before sending request with  `return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])`. So user will stay on same page after request.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def your_function(self, request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

`META['HTTP_REFERER']` stores url of referring page, if any. So you just redirect to it. But be aware, this header is not required, so it would be better to use some default_url, in case browser won't send `HTTP_REFERER` header. It could be handled like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', YOUR_DEFAULT_URL))
```

So it will redirect to `HTTP_REFERER` if it exist, and if not, it'll redirect to `YOUR_DEFAULT_URL`

Comment: its not working.a few days ago i tried this:`return redirect("./",{})` but its not working like your answer.but why(yes i import httpresponsereirect)

Comment: Strange, it works on my project. Can you specify what exactly does not work, what is happening after this redirect? Try `return HttpResponseRedirect("../")` @Abdullah

Comment: like before.redirect me root directory

Comment: Yes you are right, it's redirect to root. Try `return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)`. @Abdullah

Comment: this is enter infinity redirect loop.(i tried this too but its should worked.strange)

Comment: I guess you need to redirect to page where user was **before** he send request, then try this `HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])`. The previous solution returns you to the request address

Comment: nobody could help me? this was important to my project and it was the last thing in my project:(

Comment: Specify what exactly does not work, what is happening after this return `return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])`? @Abdullah

Comment: like before.redirect me to root directory

Comment: try print `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` before return, what's there? @Abdullah

Comment: thanks @weAreStarDust.its work for me.but i not understand this.please tell me this mean or show me this source.rethanks guy.

Comment: Glad to hear, accept the answer if it was useful. META['HTTP_REFERER'] stores url of referring page, if any. So you just redirect to it. But be aware, this header is not required, so it woulde be better to use some default_url, in case browser woun't send `HTTP_REFERER` header. It could be handle like this `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', YOUR_DEFAULT_URL)`. @Abdullah

Answer (score 0):

You can use render

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...
return render(request, 'yourTemplate.html', {'isfav': isfav})
```